# Flask-Reatful unit testing response 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, flask-restful

I use Flask-Reatful to build Flask Restful. But when I did a unit test, I was able to get the hello response, and the login returned a response of 404.

Am I doing something wrong?

Code:
 https://gist.github.com/LuGuoHuas/3578cf0c8681638afb288b5d796760a4

Comment: I don't see a route to "/hello" -- am I missing something?

Comment: @fiacre in __init__.py def create_app

Comment: Thanks.  In the test setUp method, would you print self.app?

Comment: @fiacre print self.app is <Flask 'resources'> and print self.client is <FlaskClient <Flask 'resources'>>.like this?

Comment: @fiacre I see only two rules in self.app, /hello and /static/<path:filename>

Answer (score 0):

Because Flask-Restful is not built after create_app, route is not loaded.